# Funnel plot with effective sample size in R

Tags: r, metafor

I am intending to create a funnel plot with an effective sample size. I am using `funnel.default()` function of `metafor` package. I tried the following code to create such a funnel plot

```
Soil_mineral_nitrogen$inv_n_tilda <-  with(Soil_mineral_nitrogen, (control_mean + treatment_mean) / (control_mean*treatment_mean))


par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
funnel(Soil_mineral_nitrogen$lnrr, Soil_mineral_nitrogen$inv_n_tilda, yaxis="ninv",
       #xlim = c(-3, 3),
       ylab = "Effective sample size (ñ)",
       xlab = "Effect size (RR)", col =Soil_mineral_nitrogen$unique_id, atransf = exp)
```

But this code is returning me an error as follows

```
Error in funnel.default(Soil_mineral_nitrogen$lnrr, Soil_mineral_nitrogen$inv_n_tilda,  : 
  No sample size information available.
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this error?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with the following code

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
funnel(Soil_mineral_nitrogen$lnrr, Soil_mineral_nitrogen$v, ni = Soil_mineral_nitrogen$inv_n_tilda, 
       yaxis="ni",
       #xlim = c(-3, 3),
       ylab = "Effective sample size (ñ)",
       xlab = "Effect size (RR)", col =Soil_mineral_nitrogen$unique_id, atransf = exp)
```